# Swedish text in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, web-config

If I have a setting of

```
<add key="emailSubject" value="Få en snabb start på ditt rökfria liv!" />
```

in a custom section within my web.config. Naturally it works fine on my local machine.

On our server however I get:

> Parser Error Message: Invalid
>   character in the given encoding.

If I change the value to use HTML equivalents for umlauts and circles over the 'a's then I get

> Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 500 (The
>   type initializer for
>   '....Sweden.ApplicationConfiguration'
>   threw an exception.)

Would anyone have any ideas on how to use umlauts and the like as config values?

If the worst comes to the worst I could hard code it but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saving as UTF-8 format should help. (BTW and possibly off-topic: I still *love* [Joel's article about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) from 2003).

Comment: In Visual Studio .NET, you can use the main menu "File", menu item "Advanced Save Options" to change the encoding.

Comment: Brilliant. I used Sublime text to "save with encoding".